# Eclipse RCP : how to get currently selected node in preference dialog

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have added a new preference page in  my application. and performing some task when user press ok button. problem is my code is executing even other node(preference page) is selected in the preference dialog.now i need to check whether currently selected node is my preference page before executing my code inside ok button. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: i have got a solution , we can check if the preference page is currently visible. `boolean visible = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getPreferenceManager().find("dk.bording.viking.rcp.cli‌​ent.serverPreferencePage").getPage().getControl().getVisible();` that works for me but if u have any better solution please share.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say, but I think your problem have started a bit earlier. If done without too many hooks and nooks, you should only be called when necessary, so it sounds a bit odd to me.

I can usually just override performOk or in some cases performApply without these problems.
[Have a look at the docs, just in case](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/preferences_prefs.htm)